# How to Access Source IP Address of Client in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ip

I'm currently working on a project where I am using API Gateway, and I need to access the source IP address of the client making requests. I understand that when using API Gateway, the original IP address of the client might not be directly accessible due to the nature of proxying.
Now , I am working with sdk and aws lambda.

With Backend SDK

```
[HttpGet]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v1")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayEvent)
    {
       
             string? message = apiGatewayEvent?.RequestContext?.Identity?.SourceIp;
             
              var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
            {
                StatusCode = 200,
                Body = message,
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", "text/plain" } }
            };

           return new ObjectResult(response);

        }
      
    }
```

and with aws Lambda

```
using Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Function
{
public APIGatewayProxyResponse FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayProxyRequest,             ILambdaContext context)
 {
    // Retrieve the client's IP address from the request context
    string clientIp = apiGatewayProxyRequest.RequestContext.Identity.SourceIp;
    
    // Your Lambda function logic goes here
    var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
    {
        StatusCode = 200,
        Body = clientIp,
        Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", "text/plain" } },
    };

     context.Logger.LogInformation($"ip address is {response}");

    return response;
  }
}
```

How can i get client ip address?

Comment: It looks like the code you have will get you the IP in the Lambda.  Can you explain what you mean by wanting to get it in API Gateway?

Comment: You are doing what you need to do - what's the issue here?